# Windows OpenCV Python: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I've seen this question answered to Linux operating systems, but I'm working with Windows (VS 2010), and I can't find a solution.

This is my code:

```
import numpy
import cv2

campo = cv2.imread("fotograma.png")
balon = cv2.imread("balon.png")

#SIFT detector
sif = cv2.SIFT()
```

I'm using Python 2.7, as I said, with VS 2010, but even if I try typping my code in the Python interpreter, it shows me the same error message. The funny thing is, when I type cv2.SI in my editor, it suggests me the SIFT function, so it looks to recognize it.

Please help me.

Comment: have you found solution to it?